# PHP Facebook SDK: Facebook can not see the Redirect Uri Param

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am testing out the latest Facebook PHP SDK v5 and do a simple oAuth login. Following the instructions in their page [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/5.0.0).

Following their instruction it manage to generate a link here:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.4/dialog/oauth?client_id=1513255468944783&amp;state=d3325fbba047b203a69b34d6a251b93d&amp;response_type=code&amp;sdk=php-sdk-5.0.0&amp;redirect_uri%5Bredirect_uri%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fmarket.deremoe.local&amp;scope=
```

Here is the code:
http://prntscr.com/8rgljl

Here is the page it displays:
http://prntscr.com/8rglw1

Why can't it see the `redirect_uri` param in the link?

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the `getLoginUrl` in SDK v5 is:

```
getLoginUrl($redirectUrl, array $scope = [], $separator = '&')
```

So you should:

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://market.deremoe.local');
```

Comment: why you htmlspecialchar the url?